# a little person can come by and pull that down on top of them

Tags: sentence-meaning

**Reporter**: Hi. Today we're here with  Captain Paul Lesley of
the fire department and he's going to give us a few tips about fire prevention around a stove.

**Captain**: Secondly, don't have your pot handles out over
the floor like this; **a little person can come by and pull that
down on top of them**. I think we'll turn the pot handle off to the side.

---

What does " **a little person can come by and pull that down on top of them**" mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

"Little person" means "child".  Its not clear to me why he would avoid the word "child".  It is probably just for variation and interest. His style is "avuncular" (literally: kindly, like an uncle to a child)

The rest is just literal:

Come by (come to the stove) and pull that (the pan) down on top of them (the child).

Young children don't know about boiling water, and if they pull down the pan they can get badly scaled. So you should not leave pot handles sticking out.

Answer (score 3):

A child may come into the kitchen and reach for the saucepan handle, pulling the pan over and spilling the hot contents over themself.